# I dispatch action in ngFor, but effect get result of last dispatch

Tags: angular, store, ngrx-effects

I loop to view card component, It loops 12 times, so dispatch action happened 12 times, I console.log inside effect to check if action dispatched or not. I found that the effect works but getting data from storage takes time while another action overwrites this action.
What can I do for disabling overwriting the previous action?

```
    @Effect()
  getOrg: Observable<Action>
    = this.actions.ofType(usersActions.GET_ORGANIZATION_DATA)
    .map((action: usersActions.GetOrganizationData) => { console.log('effect');
     return action.payload.uid; })
    .switchMap((uid) => this.usersService.getOrgByKey(uid)
      .map((Orgs: Organization) => new usersActions.GetOrganizationDataSuccess({uid: uid, org: Orgs}))
    )
    .catch(err => Observable.of(new usersActions.UsersError(err)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use mergeMap instead of switchMap.

According to rxjs [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html):

> The main difference between switchMap and other flattening operators
>   is the cancelling effect. On each emission the previous inner
>   observable (the result of the function you supplied) is cancelled and
>   the new observable is subscribed. You can remember this by the phrase
>   switch to a new observable.

Comment: I used it but I found the issue when user dispatch action in the specific component then redirect to dispatch all action and one of them already exists